# How to import TwitterUtils library from scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I am using `DSE 4.8`. I am trying to import twitterutils library by using:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
```

It's showing error:

> object twitter is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming.

Please let me know how to add package so that I can stream twitter data

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed to add dependency spark-streaming-twitter.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can alternatively use --package option to let spark auto download the jar for you if you have internet connection.

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.1.0
```

** Change version of the library as per your spark(scala) version

Comment: I m new to spark . can you tell me where to add dependency ?

Comment: So, are you using maven or any other tool for dependency management,?

Comment: If not you can try downloading jars from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10/1.6.1/spark-streaming-twitter_2.10-1.6.1.jar . But it might be having other dependencies, you need to figure it our by yourself. Better to use the dependency management tools.

Comment: Or you can use spark-shell --packages org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.1.0 to open a Spark-shell